# why wildcard cannot use `@` in Elasticsearch?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, wildcard

I want to use wildcard to search email in Elasticsearch.

For example:

```
{
  "query": {
       "wildcard": {
     "email": "*yahoo*"
    }
  }
}
```

I can get all contains `yahoo` emails. But if I search like this, no document return.

```
{
  "query": {
       "wildcard": {
     "email": "*@yahoo*"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why like this. Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't it be `.*@yahoo.*` or if you want only numbers and alphabets then `\w*@yahoo\w*`

Comment: @rock321987 sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: It should work..Cant say anything specific for `elastic search`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is the culprit in your case.

`email` field in your index seems to be `analyzed` string. So when you index it it will split into `somemail` , `yahoo.com` and these two tokens will be saved in `reverse index`. That's why you were not able to search with `@yahoo`.
You can use `analyze` api to see how your term is getting tokenized.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=standard" -d "test@yahoo.com"
```

You will get following output:

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"test","start_offset":0,"end_offset":4,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"yahoo.com","start_offset":5,"end_offset":13,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}
```

You can use [uax_url_email](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) if you want to search with `@yahoo`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: +1 Also, wildcards work for not-analyzed fields. From the docs : Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not analyzed).

Comment: @Richa Thanks for you help!

Comment: @pangpang: happy to help : )

Comment: @Richa What exactly is meant by a `reverse index` in your answer?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey `Inverted index` is the data structure used  in ES for storing tokens. Study more at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html

Comment: @Richa Oh I thought a `reverse index` was something different from an `inverted index`. Thanks anyway